# Mootools - set type="text" to an input that has type="password" does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, passwords, mootools

I have the following Mootools code, to add a value on focus/blur in a password field:

```
  $$('#connect_login_box #password-element > input').set('value','Password').set('type', 'text').addEvents({
    focus: function(){ 
      if (this.value=='Password') this.set('type', 'password').addClass('input_active').value=''; },
    blur: function(){
      if (this.value=='') this.set('type', 'text').removeClass('input_active').value='Password'; }
```

This code does not work in IE8, and it breaks all the other JS on the page.
I am pretty sure that the error is produced when it gets to set('type', 'text')

Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I remember something about IE refusing to change the type of input elements (like `text` → `password`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the type of an input element once it has been set.

Remove the input element and create a new one to replace it.

Comment: thanks, I didn't knew that, because the code works in all browsers, even IE9, but not IE8.

Comment: Your idea with remove/replace the input works nicely. Thanks.